# Converting basic ActionScript 2 to ActionScript 3 for rollover animations

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript-2, flash-cs4

So, what I am trying to do ought to be simple. It's simply a rollover animation that reverses when the user rolls the mouse off. Thing is, it's in AS2 but and I think that to finish the project I'm going to need it in AS3. Can anyone give some advice on converting this...

```
stop();

this.onEnterFrame = function(){
if(rewind == true){
prevFrame();
}
}

this.onRollOver = function(){
rewind = false;
play();
}

this.onRollOut = function(){
rewind = true;
}

this.onRelease = function(){
getURL("http://www.google.com","_blank");
}
```

...into AS3? I would SERIOUSLY grateful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your code needs are limited to these, you should learn how to do it in AS3 once and for all.

Here the exact same thing in AS3

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.net.navigateToURL;
import flash.net.URLRequest;

stop();
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, onMouseOver);
addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, onMouseOut);
addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);

var rewind:Boolean = false;

function onEnterFrame(event:Event):void
{
    if (rewind == true) {
        prevFrame();
    }
}

function onMouseOver(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    rewind = false;
    play();
}

function onMouseOut(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    rewind = true;
}

function onClick(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://www.google.com"),"_blank");
}
```

Please notice that instead of creating a listener to an event (roll over for instance) by writing `this.onRollOver = function()`, you actually have to call `addEventListener` (which is pretty logical), specify the event you want to listen to and create a function called when this event is caught.

There is also another difference in `getURL`->`navigateToURL`, but I think you don't need any further explanation for it :)

As a thank you, I'd really appreciate you read this code and try to learn from it instead of copying/pasting it roughly. But hey, you're free!

Comment: Thanks very much, I am doing my best to learn but have been thrown in at the deep end with work. Learning to run before I can walk, with a potential job opportunity on the line.

Comment: That's ok, I hope you'll get the job and still want to give a look and learn a bit about AS3 afterwards!